# Python: Only keep unique values inside a list of sets

Tags: python, list, validation

right now my python function get's a list containing one or more sets...

```
l = [('val_a', 100), ('val_b', 200), ('val_a', 100), ('val_b', 200)]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove all sets inside the list, that appears more than once. If the remainig list has no more remainig sets, I want to return true. The order in which the sets can appear is absolutly random.

Examples:

```
#001 True
l = [('val_a', 100), ('val_b', 200), ('val_a', 100), ('val_b', 200)]

#002 False
l = [('val_a', 100), ('val_b', 200), ('val_a', 100), ('val_c', 300)]

#003 True
l = [('val_a', 100), ('val_a', 100)]

#004 False
l = [('val_a', 100)]
```

Also there's no need to keep the structure of the list.

Thanks for all your help and have a great day!

Comment: The list members are not sets but tuples. A set from l `set(l)` should work , since it only has unique values but no defined order.

Comment: Do you actually need the reduced list or just the true/false?

Comment: I only need the true/false information. Don't care what happens to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking whether none appear only once:

```
return 1 not in map(l.count, l)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha3GONSUtMUivNzylI1NK24FICgKLWktChPwVAhL79EITNPITexQCNHLzm_NK9ERyFHk4tL2cDAUCGkqDSVK0fBViFaQ70sMSc-UV1HwdDAQFNHAcJPAvKNkPi45GO5Cooy80o0oE6AGG-k4JaYU0yR-clAvjEu840JOh_Gx6rdBLfz0NVDghka2rBQBwA)